# Split string using sharepoint designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How can we split string using sharepoint designer 2013 workflow ( office 365 ).

I have created workflow using sharepoint designer 2013 for sharepoint online ( office 365 ) i dont **find any action to split string**.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the link https://www.codeproject.com/articles/749471/string-processing-workflow-actions-for-sharepoint which demonstrates a set of custom string processing workflow actions for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online (Office 365).

Out-of-the-box workflow actions have limited functionality of string processing. So, Reference article I shown explains about how to extend it by using the custom string processing workflow actions.

Hope this helps you.